# Excel VBA: IF ComboBox.Value statement

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Hi I have this ComboBox and I would like to do some command if the combox value says for example Paris

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()

With Sheet1.ComboBox1
.AddItem "Paris"
.AddItem "New York"
.AddItem "London"
End With

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Paris" Then
Range("A1").Value = 5
End If

End Sub
```

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want the command to run when the user changed the combobox value? If so, try looking into Event Handlers, specifically `Combobox.Change()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your code is correct, but your condition will be called only when your workbook will be opened (`WorkBook_open()`) ...

This code:

```
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Paris" Then
     Range("A1").Value = 5
End If
```

should be in an other procedure.

**Ex:** If you want `A1` to change when you select an item you can do:

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()

    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Paris"
        .AddItem "New York"
        .AddItem "London"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Paris" Then
        Range("A1").Value = 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Actually `ComboBox1_Change` is called every time `ComboBox1` value changes (pretty obvious)

**NOTE:** This code is tested and works for me, but there are other ways to do, like adding a `commandButton` and checking the condition only when this button is clicked.

Comment: @mehow Thanks! especially since you are one of the Top VBA contributors